# Nim enum converter macro?

Tags: nim-lang

Why this string to enum converter macro fails to compile? [play](https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=3vXw)

```
import std/macros, std/strutils

macro autoconvert(TT: type[enum]) =
  let fname = "to" & $(TT)
  quote do:
    converter `fname`*(s: string): `TT` = parse_enum[`TT`](s)

type Tag* = enum movies, books
autoconvert Tag
```

Error

```
play.nim(12, 13) template/generic instantiation of `autoconvert` from here
play.nim(7, 3) Error: identifier expected, but found '"toTag"'
```

UPDATE:

The solution is to use `ident "to" & $(TT)`, but why it doesn't work with just string or `newLit`?

Comment: `fname` needs to be a NimNode(of the right kind), as a macro returns AST, not a string, and because `quote` substitutes NimNodes inside backticks.

Answer (score 3):

You're using a string literal as the procedure name instead of an identifer `ident("to" & $(TT))` solves the issue, but you're also using a macro instead of a template. The reason it doesnt work with a lit is that a literal is `"toTag"` whereas an identifer is `toTag`. I suggest looking at the `treeRepr` and `repr` of the result to see what is happening. The following is the afformentioned template way.

```
import std/strutils

template autoConvert*(TT: type[enum]) {.dirty.} =
    converter toTag*(s: string): TT = parse_enum[TT](s)

type Tag* = enum movies, books
autoconvert Tag
```

Comment: Thank you! One more question, do you know if it's possible to use it as a pragma `type Tag* {.autoconvert.} = enum movies, books`?

Comment: No, presently typdef macros only get the body of that typedef and cannot emit code outside of it, so you can only modify the type not add procedures.

Comment: it is possible to add procedures to a type from a macro using an nnkStmtListType